# onClick={} com retorno de div com conteúdo da API

Tags: api, react, div

fala rapaziada. estou com um problema de iniciante... sou novo no reactjs e queria saber como faço para que: assim que eu clicar no button ele me retornar os dados da api dentro de uma DIV

ex: (article, section e etc...)

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import Api from '../API/index';

import './main.css'

class Main extends Component {

    constructor(props){
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            planets : [],
        }
    }   

    componentDidMount(){
        this.loadItens();
    }

        loadItens = async () => {
            const response = await Api.get('/planets');
            this.setState({ planets: response.data.results });
        }

render() {            
    return(    
        <div className="product-list mx-auto d-block text-center mt-5">          
              {this.state.planets.map(planetz => (
                  <article key={planetz._id} className="product-list mx-auto d-block text-center mt-5">
                      <p> Nome: {planetz.name} </p>
                      <p> Clima: {planetz.climate} </p>
                      <p> Terreno: {planetz.terrain} </p>
                      <p> População:  {planetz.population} </p>
                      <p> Participação em filmes: {planetz.films.length} </p>    

                      <button type="submit" onClick={this.loadItens}> Procurar Planetas </button>                 
                  </article>
              ))}            
        </div>
    );
};
}
export default Main;
```

Comment: João, poderia [editar](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/posts/406616/edit) sua pergunta e esclarecer seu **problema / dificuldade** ?

Comment: sim, com certeza! já foi editado... obrigado.

Comment: Mas você já não está fazendo isso? No seu `onClick` você invoca a função `loadItens`. `loadItens` busca dados no seu servidor, e então invoca o `setState` para alterar o `state` e re-renderizar o componente. Está tudo correto. O único problema é que você colocou o seu `button` dentro do loop que monta o HTML dos planetas, então se você não tiver nenhum planeta no seu `state`, você não irá entrar no loop e nenhum botão será renderizado.

Comment: @user140628 Não. eu chamei o parametro do map() dentro do article que me retornou os itens da api. eu queria saber como faço para que assim que clicar nesse botão ele me retornasse esses parametros sem precisar ter que chama-los no html. vlw!

Comment: Então ainda não entendi exatamente o que você está tentando fazer. Eu entendo que você é iniciante, mas os termos que você está utilizando para descrever esse problema não fazem sentido e isso está dificultando a comunicação. `parâmetro` é uma valor passado para uma função "chamar o parâmetro do map" é uma frase que não faz sentido. Outra coisa é que eu não estou entendendo é o que você quer dizer com "retornar esses parâmetros sem precisar chama-los no html"

Comment: ex: eu retornei dentro do article <p> Nome: {planetz.name} </p> eu queria que assim que eu clicasse no button ele me retornasse isso sem eu precisar ter que usar esse <p> Nome: {planetz.name} </p> manualmente.

Comment: O que você quer dizer por "usar <p> Nome: {planetz.name} </p> manualmente"? Desculpe, mas parece que estamos falando línguas diferentes.

Comment: precisa se desculpar não.. tudo certo!  "manualmente" não precisar chama-lo dentro article.

Comment: ao clickar no button queria que me retornasse esse map() com os itens contidos na api que no caso seriam, nome do planeta, clima,terreno,população do planeta. isso tudo apenas ao clicar no button.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fala João, tudo bem?
Veja, você quer carregar os dados só ao clicar no botão, você colocou componentDidMount chamando a API e ai ele vai trazer os dados desse jeito. tenho uma sugestão pra vc:

```js
class Main extends Component {

    constructor(props){
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            planets : [],
        }
    }   
    // Não vai ter isso aqui!
    // componentDidMount(){
    //     this.loadItens();
    // }

        loadItens = async () => {
            const response = await Api.get('/planets');
            this.setState({ planets: response.data.results });
        }

render() {            
    return(    
        <div className="product-list mx-auto d-block text-center mt-5">
         <button
            type="submit"
            onClick={this.loadItens}
         >
           Procurar Planetas
         </button>          
              {this.state.planets.length
                && this.state.planets.map(planetz => (
                  <article
                   key={planetz._id}
                   className="product-list mx-auto d-block text-center mt-5"
                  >
                      <p> Nome: {planetz.name} </p>
                      <p> Clima: {planetz.climate} </p>
                      <p> Terreno: {planetz.terrain} </p>
                      <p> População:  {planetz.population} </p>
                      <p> Participação em filmes: {planetz.films.length} </p>         
                  </article>
              ))}            
        </div>
    );
};
}
export default Main;
```

O que fiz ali foi comentar seu componentDidMount, mudar o botão de procurar planetas para logo abaixo da `<div />` para sair do loop e ficar disponível.
Coloquei também uma verificação pra rodar o map só se o planets estiver populado. (eita deu quase duplo sentido. hehehe).

Acho que assim resolve.

Comment: Para consumir uma API não é necessário sempre ter um método de ciclo de vida ? Obrigado!

Comment: Não necessariamente, João. Se ao abrir a página precisar por exemplo carregar apenas o nome dos planetas para uma listagem, aí você pode usar o componentDidMout() ou o useEffect(() => {}, []) que faz parte da nova api de Hooks do React. Esses métodos faram uma leitura inicial na API logo após a página estar carregada. 
No seu caso não era necessário, já que a comunicação com a API só ocorre após uma interação do usuário com a aplicação. No seu caso, é necessário clicar no botão primeiro. Caso não tiver ficado claro, me fala que te explico melhor.

Comment: Entendi completamente. Só tenho uma dúvida quanto ao componentDidMount... com a chamada da API com o async loadItens que eu fiz ela já está sendo consumida, certo? esse componentDidMount é apenas para renderizar o conteúdo da API em tela ? obrigado!

Comment: Esse método do ciclo de vida do React só é executado quando a página foi renderizada, ou seja, quando ela já passou pelo método render(). Eu não lembro mais de cabeça quais são todos os métodos do ciclo de vida, mas cada um executa num certo momento, tipo antes de carregar a tela (componentWillMount), antes de destruir um componente (componentWillUnMount).

Comment: Para ser mais claro, e respondendo sua pergunta, ele não serve para renderizar nada na tela. o método que renderiza é o render().

Comment: Ok. obrigado pela ajuda!